# electronics simulation circuit

Tags: power-supply, simulation, electrical

I am learning to draw electronics circuits and trying to identify the voltage and current behavior at different points of the circuit.
When learning from the internet I find simple to complex electronic circuits. Some circuits are purely using analog components and some use both analog components plus microcontroller.

What is the best simulation software where I can draw myself those circuits and learn from simulation?
I might want to draw the whole circuit.

Comment: CircuitLab is built right into this site. You can use it in your questions and/or answers. Draw your circuit, simulate it, ask questions about it, and we can run the exact same simulation. No MCUs, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a beginner, I have to say Falstad is the friendliest circuit sim to get going on. It’s easy to use and it does a really good job of visualizing current and voltage in a running circuit. It has lots of examples that you can quickly customize or copy-paste into your own design.

Try it here: http://www.falstad.com/circuit/

Two other free Spice sims are LTSpice and Microcap. They’re good, but not as interactive for learners as Falstad.

I don’t much care for CircuitLab. Its UI is kind of buggy in how it handles zoom for example, and it has a weak library.

Comment: Thanks,  @Hackastical. This is really good for a beginner like me.